# How to convert OC to Swift4 below code?

Tags: objective-c, swift4

I used OC to customize a tool class, create a button tool, how to convert this tool to swift code? In line `_buttonBlock = [button copy];` how to user copy in swift?

ToolView .h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ToolView : NSObject

+ (instancetype)shendInstance;

- (void)createButtonWithFrame:(CGRect)rect superView:(UIView *)superView buttonBlock:(void(^)(UIButton *button))button;

@end
```

ToolView.m

```
#import "ToolView.h"

typedef void(^ButtonBlock)();

@interface ToolView(){
    ButtonBlock _buttonBlock;
}

@end

@implementation ToolView

+ (instancetype)shendInstance{
    static ToolView *toolview = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        toolview = [[ToolView alloc]init];
    });
    return toolview;
}

- (void)createButtonWithFrame:(CGRect)rect superView:(UIView *)superView buttonBlock:(void(^)(UIButton *button))button{
    _buttonBlock = [button copy];
    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    btn.frame = rect;
    btn.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [superView addSubview:btn];
}

- (void)buttonAction:(UIButton *)sender{
    if (_buttonBlock) {
        _buttonBlock(sender);
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

> In line _buttonBlock = [button copy]; how to user copy in swift?

You don't copy the block parameter in Swift, instead you mark the parameter as *escaping*. You Swift function will be declared something like:

```
fun createButton(frame: CGRect,
                 superView: UIView,
                 buttonBlock: @escaping (UIButton) -> Void
                )
```

See *Escaping Closures* in the [The Swift Programming Language: Closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html).

Comment: `buttonBlock` is button selector callback, not UIButton,how to fix?

Comment: By declaring the block parameter as escaping you can assign it to your instance variable. This is covered in *EscapingClosures*. Am I misunderstanding what you are asking?

Answer (score -1):

I converted it, myself code below:

ToolView.swift

```
import UIKit
class ToolView: NSObject {

    static let instance: ToolView = ToolView()
    class func shareInstance() -> ToolView{
        return instance
    }

    var blockActionBlock:((UIButton) -> Void)?

    func createButton(frame: CGRect, superView: UIView, buttonBlock: @escaping (UIButton) ->Void) -> Void { //
        let button = UIButton()
        button.frame = frame
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        superView .addSubview(button)
        button .addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.buttonAction), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        blockActionBlock = buttonBlock
    }

    @objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton){
        blockActionBlock!(sender)
    }
}
```

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ToolView .shareInstance().createButton(frame: CGRect(x:100, y: 100, width:100, height:50), superView: self.view) { (button) in
            print("Click Button \(button)")
        }
    }
}
```